# FlexLayout height not updating while content height is changed

Tags: ios, swift, angular-flex-layout

I am using following flexlayout library for design my ios App. 
https://github.com/layoutBox/FlexLayout#api_documentation

i have some problem with this. i write the simple code like this

```
//Basic Info Card
            let card = CardView()
            card.cornerRadius = 5
            card.shadowOpacity = 0.5
            card.backgroundColor = .white
            flex.addItem(card).direction(.column).marginTop(16).padding(16).backgroundColor(.blue).define({flex in
                basicInfoTextView.isEditable = true
                basicInfoTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
                flex.addItem(basicInfoTextView).backgroundColor(.red).width(100%).minHeight(20)
                basicInfoTextView.delegate = self
            })

// Delegate
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if textView == basicInfoTextView {
            print(basicInfoTextView.intrinsicContentSize.height)
            basicInfoTextView.flex.height(basicInfoTextView.intrinsicContentSize.height)
            basicInfoTextView.flex.markDirty()
            basicInfoTextView.flex.layout(mode: .adjustHeight)                
        }            
        return true
    }
```

[image: y]

UITextview properly update it's height based on user input. But it's container not updating. it's still in initial height of UITextView like minHeight of 20. What was is wrong here. Please help me thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest you do this first with standard constraint setup. Then, when you have it working the way you want, change it to use "FlexLayout" (if you want to). It sounds like you don't really understand how constraints work, and so what you're trying to do with the FlexLayout library isn't correct.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I am really don't understand constraints. That's why i am moving to FlexLayout (Dynamic Views). I am totally confusing in Constraint for following techs. Like wrap contents. ScrollViews.

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing a call to **layoutSubviews()** in **shouldChangeTextIn**. I recommend putting the logic inside the **textViewDidChange** delegate method instead, so you can have the updated height *after* the user types something in the text view. Here's a link to a working example [gist](https://gist.github.com/elaine-herrera/00b37ae35e49d15d791db50be8a7932d)